# Why must it always be this way?

Tags: discussion

You don't like the question, or you think no answer exists, so you slam some ridiculous cut and paste text that doesn't even remotely apply, and you put the question on hold.

Go to any meta page for any SE site, and you'll see the same thing over and over.

Today I couldn't find an answer to something, so I made the mistake of trying to ask the question here:  https://serverfault.com/questions/584749/what-microsoft-server-os-will-follow-microsoft-server-2012-r2

My question included some anecdotal background and concluded with this question:

> Is Microsoft working on a new OS to succeed 2012 R2?
>
> Countless searches to SE and Google, and I'm unable to find anything.
>   I hope this question is appropriate here in Server Fault. I searched
>   the SE index, and I was surprised to discover that there is no Windows
>   SE! If you feel that this question is not appropriate for Server
>   Fault, alternative suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The downvotes started immediately, sans comments.  So I added a comment to my own question:

> If you feel that this question is not appropriate for Server Fault,
>   alternative suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Five seconds
>   after posting this question, with this request included, the downvotes
>   commence. No comments.... Super helpful.

I don't know if you can tell, but this is incredibly frustrating.  I know I am not alone in this feeling, because I participate on multiple SE sites, and I see this over and over again.  I knew what was coming, but I had no one else to ask.

Now, my question is closed.  Reportedly, my question is based on opinion.

You don't need to respond.  I didn't write this post to have a dialog and feel better about the treatment I got today, but rather to hopefully open your eyes to a serious problem here at SE.

This attitude drives people away on a daily basis.  The only person who can change it is you.  Stop with the cutting and pasting and be an actual human being for five seconds.  Explain to the person the real reason you don't like their question, instead of creating some excuse, and maybe you'll provide an opportunity for growth.

Right now the only thing that seems to be growing is cancer.

Comment: Ask Microsoft. The rest of us can only guess. And if you don't want a dialogue, then there is no point to this post at all.

Comment: Your question does not fall in the scope of server fault. The basic litmus test is "is it a real problem? Does it need solving?" This is not a real problem. It's just someone wondering out aloud. There is nothing to be solved. The general public won't know the answer to you question, and anyone who does will be under an NDA. We don't allow "general discussion" questions, and never have.

Comment: Your question was treated the same way it would have been if one of us had asked it and probably better.  You at least got comments from myself and others that explained why it was an off-topic question and what our "opinion" was at that point.  If one of the regulars had posted that we would have flamed them like crazy and then ribbed them in Chat as well.  It wasn't **YOU** that the downvotes and comments were directed at...it was the **QUESTION**.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because by the OPs own addmission they are just having a whinge to feel better.

`You don't need to respond. I didn't write this post to have a dialog and feel better about the treatment I got today, but rather to hopefully open your eyes to a serious problem here at SE. `

Comment: @MichaelHampton The purpose of this post was to insight discussion among you all, the perpetrators of the problem.  You have nothing to discuss with me that will be of any value to this site.  As you can see, all of these comments above are directed at me (what you all perceive to be the source of the problem) rather than any meaningful discussion about the way that we conduct business here on SE.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Thank you Mark.  As you are undboutedly aware, this explanation would have been far less frustrating than the one I received.  Therein lies the problem.

Comment: @Lumberjack: had you read our [about](http://serverfault.com/about) page you'd have saved everyone including yourself the trouble - therein lies the main problem.

Comment: You haven't raised any issues that "we" (whoever "we" are) might need to discuss _with each other_. In particular, you haven't identified a problem. And if we have nothing to discuss with _you_ then there really is no point. Goodbye.

Comment: @Lumberjack You didn't read what the site was [about] and then you asked a question that is very much off-topic and appeared to get upset that people didn't bother to tell you why. You appear to have enough rep on other SE sites to know that these sites aren't a free-for-all. I'm not sure why you think the problem lies anywhere other than on the asker here.

Comment: @MDMarra Let us take it as given that I am at fault, that I asked a bad question.  Is it appropriate to close an off=topic question with any tag other than off-topic?  Or does it perhaps illicit this sort of response when we close a question with an obviously wrong reason stated?  I don't know why others participate in SE, but I know why I do.  I participate to help people.  For this reason, you can often find my answers as comments to closed or on hold questions.  If I don't know the answer, I'll at least try to point the asker in the right direction.

Comment: @MDMarra The problem I wanted to illuminate is most perfectly demonstrated by the one "answer" below.  The insider has such vitriol for the outsider.  I just can't understand where it comes from, and I've observed the problem on many SE sites.  I stopped participating on ESS for this very reason.

Comment: @Lumberjack Iain doesn't have vitriol for the outsider. As he articulates, he has vitriol for the outsider that can't be bothered to read the help page and ensure that what he's asking is on-topic.

Comment: @MDMarra  This question in meta is another great example.  This question is not off topic.  It directly relates to two of the bullet points in the off-topic boiler plate, yet it has been put on-hold.  I can only speculate as to why, but my best guess is to silence the voice of dissent.

Comment: `I don't know why others participate in SE, but I know why I do.` - I also like to help people, as evidenced by my 1,914 answers and 75,370 rep. The problem is that there are two kinds of new users. The kind that mean well, read the rules, and ask appropriately detailed questions and the kind that ignore the rules, ask whatever they want, and get bent out of shape when they are told that they did it wrong. You fall into bucket #2. Users that fall into bucket #1 are generally met with helpful responses.

Comment: `This question in meta is another great example. This question is not off topic. It directly relates to two of the bullet points in the off-topic boiler plate, yet it has been put on-hold.` I'd also point out that you don't ask a question in this meta post. You rant. There isn't a single question mark outside of the blockquotes from your now-deleted question on main. A genuinely constructive question about the rules is fine for meta. Ranting is not. Again - take a minute to familiarize yourself with the rules next time and you may make out better than you did this time.

Comment: @EEAA I understand the distinction, but I don't know that it is all that meaningful.  I did in fact read the about page before posting my question.  The topic of my question is not covered by the "don't ask" section, and it is covered by the first bullet-point of the "do ask."  It might be obvious to an insider that my question is a bad question, but it is not always obvious to the person asking.

Comment: @MDMarra I have just re-read the "About" page, and I am still unable to identify the section that details why I shouldn't have asked the Windows Server question on Server Fault.  The best explanation was provided by #MarkHenderson " The basic litmus test is "is it a real problem? Does it need solving?" This is not a real problem. "  Perhaps the About page should be updated to include something so concisely worded.  My "question" was intended to give some insight into the feelings generated by this behavior.  Surely having spent enough time to garner 75k rep, you have seen this behavior ...

Comment: And to answer your actual question - of course they are working on another OS. Client and server operating system SKUs have been released together since Windows 7/2008 R2. In fact, client/server SKUs share the same kernel and everything now. There are leaked internal builds on Windows 9 on the Internet, so it's safe to assume that the next Windows Server version is also under development. Microsoft isn't going to stop making new operating systems.

Comment: @MDMarra I'm not so egocentirc as to believe that I am perfect, but how many thousands of people have to make the claims I've made today, before somebody considers that perhaps SE can improve in some small way to make a difference?

Comment: @Lumberjack it's **right there** `"Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."` The question isn't about a problem you have faced. It's literally right there in bold typeface.

Comment: Anyway, I hope you eventually figure out why you seem to be swimming upstream here. I've tried to help you understand what you're missing, but if you don't get it by now, I can't help you any further.

Comment: @MDMarra Can you provide a link, because Ctrl-F for your text is bringing up nothing on the page: http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You don't even have to go all the way to the on-topic section. It's right in [about]. http://i.imgur.com/qpfDOMP.png the [Don't ask](http://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask) section also spells this out: `"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."`

Comment: @MDMarra Someone should add some text to this affect in the on-topic section.  Also, adding some text illuminating this point on the Ask A Question page would go a long way to reducing the frequency of these problems, and improve the experience of SE users.

Comment: @EEAA I think the on-topic page http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic needs to be updated.  I did read it before posting my question, and I think you should read it too.  My question wasn't open ended.  It wasn't "general discussion."  It wasn't opinion based.  It was off topic, because it wasn't a problem that needed to be solved.  The on-topic section makes no mention of this particular caveat.  And for the record MDMarra did a fine job of answering my question above.  Had things gone differently, MDMarra's answer would likely have a green check mark next to it.

Comment: This conversation has run its course. Please don't make me lock it again. It's the *internet* people.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't see your question before it was closed but had I done so I would have voted to close it the same as other people did. I may even have chucked a downvote on it and not left a comment.

Do you realise how frustrating it is to have a daily deluge of crappy off topic questions asked by people who have completely missed every opportunity to familiarise themselves with our topicality and scope ?

Do you realise just how frustrating it is to then have them come to meta and whinge about their failings that the community had to clean up ?

Do you realise just how frustrating it is to have people not read the text provided as part of the close reason<sup>1</sup> ?

...

<sup>1</sup>It's not copy+paste text it boilerplate that it automagically inserted when a question is closed. It includes valuable information on why the community felt that your question was not within scope/topical for Server Fault. You should read it and attempt to understand it within the scope of Server Fault.

Comment: It is unfortunate that your reply is directed at me.  The discussion you should be having is with your comrades here.  With that said, I will do you the service of responding anyhow.

Comment: Do you realise how frustrating it is to have a daily deluge of crappy....   You are an insider and so you act and think like an insider, with vitriol for the perceived outsider.  This is the problem.

Comment: Do you realise just how frustrating it is to then have them come to meta.... You're being presented an opportunity to grow as a community, and you're using it as a circle jerk instead.  Your choice.

Comment: Do you realise just how frustrating it is to have people not read the text provided.... I read the text.  It was my inability to understand said "boiler plate text" that led me to post here.

Comment: @Lumberjack: Your 'question' isn't about the text it's just a whiney whinge.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Its only a waste of time because you are unwilling to think about the problem from any perspective but your own.  So be it.

Comment: The about page is virtually hidden in comparison to the many resources provided by the site to help an asker determine if his question is appropriate or not.  The about page is a tiny text only link hidden in the footer section of the main page.  By contrast, if you click Ask A Question, the sidebar reads: Review our list of allowed topics. We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.  The "list of allowed topics" is a link that takes you to the Help Page for Asking.  It lists what is on-topic and what is off-topic.  http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I suspect (and site analysis could confirm) that the about page gets many less hits than the on-topic page.  In any case, the on-topic page should include some text illustrating the point that has been repeated here.  furthermore, given how painfully frustrating it is for everyone here to deal with a "daily deluge of crappy off topic questions asked by people who have completely missed every opportunity to familiarise themselves with our topicality and scope."  Maybe you could consider that your perspective isn't the only one.  Perhaps it is possible that one of these annoying people ...

Comment: could have actually attempted to verify the validity of his question before asking it.  Maybe this information that is so universally obvious to an insider isn't as ubiquitous as you perceive.  If that is the case you should be my loudest supporter in asking that this detail be more widely published on the site.  Would not better communication help to reduce the frequency of both our frustrations?